# How do I change the redirect url in Keycloak Spring Java integration

Tags: spring, spring-security, keycloak

I want to change the redirect_url in Keycloak. But am not sure how I can modify it. The redirected url should be on a completely different domain. I'm using spring security and it automatically assigns the redirect_url.